# How to create an array of pseudo-random numbers that are spread out over an interval?

Tags: javascript, random

I would like to create an array of n (`steps`) integers within an interval [a (`min`), b (`max`)] which can be done like this (there are probably smarter ways):

```js
function randomFromInterval(min, max, steps) {
  return new Array(steps).fill(0).map(n => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min));
}

console.log(randomFromInterval(1, 100, 10));
```

Unfortunately, with [truly random integers](https://xkcd.com/221/), it could happen that the result of `randomFromInterval(1, 100, 5)` is for example `[1,2,3,4,5]` which I would like to mitigate. The values of `randomFromIntervalButSpread(min, max, steps)` should therefore be spread out over the interval in such a way that

```
randomFromIntervalButSpread(0, 4, 5) => [0,1,2,3,4]
randomFromIntervalButSpread(10, 60, 5) => [1X,2X,3X,4X,5X] // X being 0-9
.
.
.
```

To summarize: The numbers should be random in the sense that if steps > |[min, max]| the results differ from iteration to iteration but are never grouped together within the interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short function:

```js
function randomFromIntervalButSpread(min, max, steps) {
  return new Array(steps).fill(0).map((n, i) => Math.floor(Math.random()*((max-min)/steps+1)+(i*(max-min))/steps+min));
}

console.log(randomFromIntervalButSpread(0, 5, 5))
console.log(randomFromIntervalButSpread(100, 200, 10))
```

+ shuffle:

```js
function randomFromIntervalButSpread(min, max, steps) {
  return new Array(steps).fill(0).map((n, i) => Math.floor(Math.random()*((max-min)/steps+1)+(i*(max-min))/steps+min)).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}

console.log(randomFromIntervalButSpread(0, 5, 5))
console.log(randomFromIntervalButSpread(100, 200, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the steps and generate values with the appropriate floor and ceiling. Note that in this function, `end` is exclusive.

```js
function randomFromIntervalButSpread(start, end, intervals) {
  var arr = [];
  var range = (end - start) / intervals;

  // Generates a value between start and start + range
  // Moves start up to the next step
  while (start < end) {
    arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * range + start));
    start += range;
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(randomFromIntervalButSpread(0, 5, 5))
console.log(randomFromIntervalButSpread(1, 100, 10))
```

Comment: The maximum value is never included in the resulting array

Comment: ```randomFromIntervalButSpread(10, 60, 5) => [1X,2X,3X,4X,5X] // X being 0-9``` according to your specification, it's not supposed to be.